# Soundcloud stratus component broken. Uncaught ReferenceError: soundManager is not defined player.js:10

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundcloud, soundcloud-stratus

```
Re: nov25 Deploys/updates made from 11.18 - 11.24
```

Hi!
    My stratus component stopped working today in dev and (stable) production environments.
    I am seeing the following script error in chrome on OS X:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: soundManager is not defined player.js:10
window.Track.Backbone.Model.extend.initialize player.js:10
Backbone.Model backbone.js:137
child backbone.js:1110
_.extend._prepareModel backbone.js:571
_.extend._add backbone.js:584
_.extend.add backbone.js:449
(anonymous function) player.js:247
(anonymous function) sdk.js:1
request.onreadystatechange sdk.js:1
```

Up 'til yesterday night the stratus component was working fine for a month (at least) no problems. I didn't change anything in my code.

Then this afternoon I checked and stratus is failing now.

I'm using the current style & script
    http://stratus.sc/stratus.css && http://stratus.sc/stratus.js

And my javascript hook from java is as follows

```
public String getScript() {
    return "    <script type=\"text/javascript\">\n" +
           "        $(document).ready(function(){\n" +
           "            $.stratus({\n" +
           "                links: '"+getUrl()+"'\n" +
           "            });\n" +
           "        });\n" +
           "    </script>";
}
```

Any idea what could be happening here?
Thanks, Jon

Some random words to satiate the regex. Why should I need to add more details? It seems quite unnecessary to me. Good lord how much do I need to add to make this validation happy?

Comment: Apparently the SoundManager2 Library has been dropped and is replaced with the AudioManager to support RTMP streaming. See this commit: https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-javascript/commit/3ee64f9a9864078348a445a51a3b133933ac74b1.

Comment: That's unfortunate. From what I briefly read RTMP is some vestige of Adobe flash. I didn't/don't really want anything to do with Adobe flash ever. It's most likely insecure bloat and like I said, I don't think I want any of that.

Comment: It seems like SoundManager2 has been restored (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20206274/soundcloud-api-setvolume-on-audiomanager-js/20214417#20214417). Be sure to clear your cache and see if your app is working again.