# SoundCloud API: setVolume on audiomanager.js

Tags: javascript, soundcloud, soundmanager2

We've been having problems with the setVolume function while using the SoundCloud Javascript API.

The trace:

Uncaught IndexSizeError: Index or size was negative, or greater than the allowed value. audiomanager.js:2
HTML5AudioPlayer.setVolume

We are calling that function on the sound object, as usual, and the values we're passing to are between 0 and 100, which are the ones that are specified as correct.

The problem started a few hours ago and we haven't made any changes in our code, so it seems that the version of audiomanager we're retrieving from soundcloud has changed today.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you mean SoundManager?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the SoundCloud JavaScript SDK has changed over night. I'm facing similar issues. The SDK is using the HTML5AudioPlayer object now to stream tracks. As for you question, I've noticed that the volume value needs to be between 0 and 1 opposed to 0 and 100 in the "old" version. So be sure to call `sound.setVolume(0.5)` instead of `sound.setVolume(50)`. Also, the "whileplaying" event is not firing anymore.

It would be nice of SoundCloud to update their docs / inform devs about SDK changes in the future. In the mean time, I'm looking at https://connect.soundcloud.com/audiomanager/audiomanager.js to find answers to my questions.

Comment: Apparently the SoundManager2 Library has been dropped and is replaced with the AudioManager to support RTMP streaming. See this commit: https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-javascript/commit/3ee64f9a9864078348a445a51a3b133933ac74b1.

Comment: For the moment they've removed [audiomanager.js](https://connect.soundcloud.com/audiomanager/audiomanager.js) and brought back [soundmanager2.js](http://connect.soundcloud.com/soundmanager2/soundmanager2.js) (responded with 404 about a hour ago). Can't wait to find out what they've planned — lots of third party players such as [Stratus 2](http://stratus.sc/) are broken now because of that.

Comment: Thanks guys. As @jibiel said, now it's bringing soundmanager2.js, instead of audiomanager.js. I'm trying to reproduce the tracks after invoking the stream function as described here: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#playing. Apparently I'm receiving the sound object on the callback function, but calling play() on that object doesn't seem to have any effect. As I said before, no changes have been made on the code from our side, and it has been working fine for months. Does anybody have any update? The docs haven't been updated yet.

Comment: @drenzulli, show us some code if you need further help. Have you checked the SoundManager2 docs: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/? Also, did you set the volume back between 0 and 100 instead of 0 - 1?

Comment: Looks like they're trying to implement some kind of backward compatibility (I hope). `soundmanager2.js` (note that is `dev` build) appeared again in [SDK](http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js) alongside with `audiomanager.js`.

Comment: Indeed, looks like they have changed some things again. My app is now requesting https://connect.soundcloud.com/soundmanager2/soundmanager2_flash9_debug.swf, which returns a 404. I haven't changed anything. Also, I just found this: http://connect.soundcloud.com/examples/streaming.html, these might be the new docs?

Comment: Apparently they're rolling out the fix now, it should be ready in a couple of hours. I recommend you to follow them on twitter https://twitter.com/SCsupport, they're doing a good work answering questions there.

Comment: Ok. They've [returned](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-javascript/commit/64dbb7000106a3e887abe3d6c8b6166e8fc98ad4) to the previous state of SDK. But only till the major version release. So be ready, guys.